# How to determine if binding of certificate to port has been done?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, owin, netsh

I have set up an OWIN selfhost on a machine where I registered a certificate for a specific port using the command:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8082 certhash=<cert_thumbprint_here> appid={00000000-0000-0000-0000-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

My OWIN host is started for this URL:

```
using (WebApp.Start<OwinStartup>(url: https://my-pc:8082))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

What I would like to know is if it is possible with C# to determine if there is a binding of the certificate to this port. Basically, I want to check in my application if the netsh command has been executed on the server of the user, because OWIN will run just fine on https, but no one will be able to connect.

Comment: You can execute `netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8082` and parse the results.  There's probably also a way to use PowerShell, which will save you from parsing results.

Comment: You can PInvoke the related HTTP API. I am open sourcing Jexus Manager next year and then I can show you some sample code. But no one can connect to your site might be caused by other factors, so you should dive deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find if the binding has been done you need to check what is happening with that particular port.
To do so you need to execute a command in CMD like below:

```
netstat -o -n -a | find /c "0.0.0.0:8082"
```

This command will give you no of socket active on a specific IP (0.0.0.0) and port(8082)

This is the CMD that you can execute it using C# as below:

```
            try
            {
                var configProc = new ProcessStartInfo();
                string cmdConfig = @"netstat -o -n -a | find /c "0.0.0.0:8082";
                configProc.UseShellExecute = true;

                configProc.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
                configProc.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
                configProc.Verb = "runas";
                configProc.Arguments = "/c " + cmdConfig;
                configProc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process.Start(configProc);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```